# Linker errors when try to compile app with 7z.dll on Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, dll, 7zip, unresolved-external

I try to compile simple application on Qt5 (Windows 7) using 7z.dll. I use code samples from 7zip Client7z example, but i get next errors:

```
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SysAllocString@4 referenced in function "long __cdecl StringToBstr(wchar_t const *,wchar_t * *)" (?StringToBstr@@YAJPB_WPAPA_W@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class CStringBase<wchar_t> __cdecl ConvertPropVariantToString(struct tagPROPVARIANT const &)" (?ConvertPropVariantToString@@YA?AV?$CStringBase@_W@@ABUtagPROPVARIANT@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainWindow::getArchiveContent(class QString const &)" (?getArchiveContent@MainWindow@@AAEXABVQString@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall NWindows::NCOM::CPropVariant::Clear(void)" (?Clear@CPropVariant@NCOM@NWindows@@QAEJXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall NWindows::NCOM::CPropVariant::~CPropVariant(void)" (??1CPropVariant@NCOM@NWindows@@QAE@XZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall NWindows::NFile::NIO::CInFile::Open(wchar_t const *)" (?Open@CInFile@NIO@NFile@NWindows@@QAE_NPB_W@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall CInFileStream::Open(wchar_t const *)" (?Open@CInFileStream@@QAE_NPB_W@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CInFileStream::Read(void *,unsigned int,unsigned int *)" (?Read@CInFileStream@@UAGJPAXIPAI@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CInFileStream::Seek(__int64,unsigned int,unsigned __int64 *)" (?Seek@CInFileStream@@UAGJ_JIPA_K@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long __stdcall CInFileStream::GetSize(unsigned __int64 *)" (?GetSize@CInFileStream@@UAGJPA_K@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CInFileStream::~CInFileStream(void)" (??1CInFileStream@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall CInFileStream::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GCInFileStream@@UAEPAXI@Z)
debug\archive.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
```

I will be grateful for any help in correcting these errors.

Comment: Do you link against 7z.dll? LIBS += -l7z -L/path/to/7z. Also note that you can't C++ libraries compiled with MSVC in a mingw-compiled binary and vice versa.

Comment: I get 7z.dll and 7z.lib from CPP\7zip\Bundles\Format7zF\ folder, compiled with MSVC 2010 (for Qt i also used MSVC compilator). Also I add win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -l7z string to pro file. But it doesn't help.

Comment: first error was fixed by adding LIBS += -loleaut32 -lole32 string in pro file